# Add attribute (clustering coefficient) to graph and plot graph, with node size proportional to CC

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph:

```
from networkx.generators.random_graphs import *
from networkx.algorithms.cluster import *

G = fast_gnp_random_graph(20,0.4)
```

I calculate clustering for each node:

```
clust_net = clustering(G)
    cluster = []
    for a in clust_net:
        cluster.append(clust_net[a])
```

This yields an array. I then create a dictionary linking clustering coefficient to node:

```
node_cluster = dict(zip(G.nodes(), cluster))
```

How can I use this to make a graph with node_size dependent on clustering coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `node_size` keyword argument for `nx.draw()`. This takes a list of values by which to scale the nodes in the plot.

You can also simplify your code a little bit, as at the moment, when you calculate `node_cluster`, it has exactly the same structure as `clustering(G)`.

The below example sets an attribute `'cc'` for each node in the graph, and then plots the graph, scaling node size proportionally based on the value of that attribute.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(20,0.4)

nx.set_node_attributes(G, nx.clustering(G), "cc")

nx.draw(G,
        node_size=[G.nodes[x]['cc']*1000 for x in G.nodes],
        with_labels=True)
```

### Output:

```
>>> nx.clustering(G)
{0: 0.4,
 1: 0.37777777777777777,
 2: 0.3333333333333333,
 3: 0.26666666666666666,
 4: 0.3787878787878788,
 5: 0.34545454545454546,
 6: 0.4,
 7: 0.1,
 8: 0.26666666666666666,
 9: 0.4666666666666667,
 10: 0.2857142857142857,
 11: 0.4444444444444444,
 12: 0.3,
 13: 0.4,
 14: 0.6190476190476191,
 15: 0.4,
 16: 0.4,
 17: 0.3888888888888889,
 18: 0.7333333333333333,
 19: 0.2857142857142857}
```

### [image]